# Using CellPrint with a TraditionalForm string

Tags: output-formatting, display, traditional-form

I am trying to use CellPrint to print a cell that asks a user to solve an equation.  This equation is randomly generated right beforehand, and I would like to have it print in Blue.  The whole Cell should be in the "Section" style.  Here is my first attempt:

```
equat = ToString[
Expand[Product[(x - RandomInteger[{-10, 10}]), {i, 
  3 + RandomInteger[]}]], TraditionalForm];
CellPrint[
Cell[TextData[
RowBox[{StyleBox["Solve the equation "], 
  StyleBox[equat, FontColor -> Blue]}]], "Section"]];
```

This does in fact create the cell, and the last part is blue, but it is hindered by the TraditionalForm "markup": I won't put any color here, but the command above gives the output

```
Solve the equation \!\(TraditionalForm\`\(x\^4 - \(\(73\ x\^2\)\) - \(\(72\ x\)\)\)\)
```

Is there a simple way to fix this? I have tried using ToBoxes, but then I don't see how to color the output Blue. Any tips or pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: How about `equ = TraditionalForm@
  Expand[Product[(x - RandomInteger[{-10, 10}]), {i, 
     3 + RandomInteger[]}]];CellPrint[
 Cell[CellGroupData[{StyleBox["Solve the equation "], 
    BoxData[ToBoxes@equ]}]]]`

Comment: @DavidCarraher: That prints two different cells, no?

Comment: Ah but this does give me a way to work it out: equ = TraditionalForm@
  Expand[Product[(x - RandomInteger[{-10, 10}]), {i, 
     3 + RandomInteger[]}]]; CellPrint[
 Cell[RowBox[{StyleBox["Solve the equation ", "Section"], 
    StyleBox[ToBoxes@equ, FontColor -> Blue, FontWeight -> Bold, 
     "Section"]}]]]

Comment: Now the hard part :) - how to put an "=0" at the end (in blue)?

Comment: Maybe...`equ = TraditionalForm[
   Expand[Product[(x - RandomInteger[{-10, 10}]), {i, 
       3 + RandomInteger[]}]] == HoldForm[0]];`

Comment: Actually, the `HoldForm` is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarraher! Maybe you could post this as an answer? I still would like to see other approaches (I'd prefer to be able to work with equ as a String), but this definitely gets the job done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use BoxData. 
Because ToString creates something strange you also obviously have to change "\\" -> "".
I don't know if this is a bug or working as designed.

```
equat = (StringReplace[ToString[#1, TraditionalForm], "\\" -> ""] & )[
       Expand[
    Product[x - RandomInteger[{-10, 10}], {i, 3 + RandomInteger[]}]]]; 
CellPrint[
  Cell[BoxData[{RowBox[{"Solve the equation ", 
       StyleBox[equat, FontColor -> Blue]}]}], "Section"]];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I wanted.